# Minimum flips required to make path between source and destination in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

An extension of problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-path-two-cells-matrix/

Here one has to find if path exists in a `top left` to `bottom right` corner of matrix . There will be obstacles in between as stated in problem . Now my question is if there exists no path from source to destination , what are minimum obstacles that has to be flipped in a matrix to build:

- a) A path.
- b) Shortest path

between source and destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more clarity to your problem, lets assume we will be given a two dimensional grid with `row` number of rows and `col` number of columns of integers containing integer `0` and `1`.

**0** : blank cell. 
 **1** : obstacle.

You want to know minimum obstacles that has to be flipped in a matrix to build **path and Shortest path** starting from top left to bottom right corner of matrix ?

**a) Path with minimum number of obstacle:**
We can find path with minimum number of obstacles simply applying breadth first search (BFS) or depth first search (DFS) and taking cost of entering into blank space as `0` and cost entering into obstacle as `1`. And, from each cell we can traverse all directions up, down, right and left. The distance of shortest path calculated in this way will give us the minimum obstacle flipping path from top left to bottom right corner of matrix.

**b) Shortest path with minimum number of obstacle:**
The shortest possible path length starting from top left to bottom right corner of matrix will always be same which is equal to row + col - 2 which can be achieved by traversing either right or down directions from each cell in grid. So, this problem can also be solved using BFS or DFS and traversing only right or down from each cell and taking cost of entering into blank space as `0` and cost entering into obstacle as `1`. The distance of shortest path calculated in this way will give us the minimum number of obstacles to be flipped to go from top left to bottom right corner of matrix using one of the shortest path. As there will be no cycle while traversing, we can also solve this problem using dynamic programming.

Comment: makes sense . that was helpful.